# How do i redirect people to the login if not logged using localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to do an exercise where I'm ask to do a login using local or session Storage, which has to check in the main page if the user is logged in, if they aren't it should redirect them to the login, if it is it should do nothing, but I'm having the problem that either it doesn't check the local storage or it keeps redirecting me to the login even if I already have logged in.

Sorry for my English.

This is what I've been trying.

```js
if (nombre.trim() === "" || pw.trim() === "") {
    alert("Debe ingresar su nombre.");
    console.log(nombre.trim())
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("nombre", nombre.trim());
    localStorage.setItem("pw", pw.trim());
    sessionStorage.setItem("nombre", nombre.trim());
    alert("Usuario:" + nombre + "Contraseña:" + pw)

    window.location.href = "index.html"
}

// This is what check if logged in the index:
var logeado = sessionStorage.getItem('nombre');
if (logeado === "" || logeado === null) {
    window.location.href = "login.html"
} else {
    alert('Fue logeado satisfactoriamente.')
}
```

Also I'm new at coding, in case you all didn't notice.

Comment: You're setting the values in `localStorage` but checking to see if they exist in `sessionStorage`

Comment: You appear to have an extra } at line 13

Comment: I set also a value for name in sessionStorage, just to the that check later

Comment: Please format your code. It will be easier to read. For us and for you

Comment: Also, unless this is a learning or school project, please do not use `localStorage` for authentication

Comment: @YasuoUy, do you see the alert with the name and the password when saving. And what happens if you only use localStorage. There is no real need for two different storages I think

Comment: Indeed it is a school project. I do not see the alert when saving. I tryed it using only localStorage, and the result was the same, just de login page showin up.

Comment: Well then you probably have issues while saving. Can you go to the developer tools and check the content of the local storage on the page (ie. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/localstorage/)? Is the data there?

Also you could enter some username and password there and test if the redirecting logic works then.

Comment: Be aware that your local storage will stay filled after you entered something once. That means, if you first tried if it works with the user data, and you entered something, then it will stay there even if you don't enter anything the next time.

Comment: You should not store the user password  in local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work if you never entered any credentials. However it is not possible to log a user out again, I think that might be your issue.

You really only want to check the cache if no new information is provided.

An empty string is new information.

So you should only use it when user **and** password are undefined, not when they are empty.

Here is an example that works and if I am right about your caching problem should work for you, too.

```
let user = "my_user";
let pw = "secure_password";

if (typeof user === "string") {
    user = user.trim();
}
if (typeof pw  === "string") {
    pw = pw.trim();
}

if (user === "" || pw === "") {
    localStorage.setItem("user", "");
    localStorage.setItem("pw", "");
} else if (user !== undefined && pw !== undefined) {
    localStorage.setItem("user", user);
    localStorage.setItem("pw", pw);
}

var userLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');
if (!userLoggedIn) {
  console.log("No user logged in");
} else {
  console.log(`User logged in: ${userLoggedIn}`);
}
```